# Update sqlite table by accepting new string in textfield blackberry

Tags: sql, sqlite, blackberry

I have created a customer detail table and want to update it by accepting new values that are entered in the textfield boxes for their respective columns
What would be the update statement that needs to be used for a textfield update.
Something of this sort

```
          UPDATE Customer_Detail SET textfield1=....(what next)
```

please guide

Comment: Why don't you read this link: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Working_with_SQLite_databases_1219779_11.jsp

Comment: You asked how to form SQL for update query? You asked how to get values from text fields to put them to query?

Comment: `Try to understand what the query is before posting your links!` - `SQL` is for managing data and `TextField` is an UI Component, why are you trying to relate them? Performing SQL query and retrieving values from UI Component needs to done separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 UPDATE Customer_Detail SET name = '"+TextField2.getText()+"',phone = '"+TextField3.getText()+"',email= '"+TextField4.getText()+"'  WHERE name= '"+TextField1.getText()+"'");
```

Here set the variables to capture those textfield inputs you are looking out for and in the WHERE clause use the identifier that matches your search id from table.

Answer (score 0):

What you should use are parameters.  Something like so:

```
//this is your sqlStatement - this assumes you have declared an sqlconnection and sqlstatement previous
stmt.text = "UPDATE main.tblYourTableName SET column1=:column1, column2=:column2 WHERE columnPK=0";
// setup your parameters
stmt.parameters[":column1"]= txtYourTextField1.text;
stmt.parameters[":column2"]= txtYourTextField2.text;
// execute the sql query
stmt.execute();
// clear the parameters if no longer needed or resetting the number of parameters for another sql query
stmt.clearParameters();
```

Hope this helps.

cheers,

Comment: I tried something of this sort Statement statement1 = db.createStatement("UPDATE CustDet SET name = '"+TextField2.getText()+"',phone = '"+TextField3.getText()+"',email= '"+TextField4.getText()+"'  WHERE name= '"+TextField1.getText()+"'"); Whats ur opinion on dis

Comment: Actually what language are you coding in.  If using Flex my answer gives it, if using Java then the link supplied gives the answer.

Comment: its for blackberry java.whats your opinion about using a update statement like in my prev comment.